# how to prevent the delay from ip camera frame in python

Tags: python

I use requests module in python 3 and ide spider. It run to web page unproblematic when I selected frame resolution 1920X1080 and frame rate 25 fps. But It is a delay to occur to my code in python. It run normally when I altered frame rate 10 fps or resolution 1280x720

```
    r = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('username', 'pass'), 
    stream=True)               
    def get_frame_from_stream(r):
      if(r.status_code == 200):
      bytes=b'' 
      for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=None):
      bytes += chunk
      a = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd8')
      b = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd9')
      if a != -1 and b != -1:
      jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
      bytes = bytes[b+2:] 
      frame=cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer
      jpg,dtype=np.uint8)cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
      cv2.imshow('Live',frame)
      time.sleep(0.004) 
      if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        exit(0)
      else: 
      print('status code error',r.status_code)
```

Comment: Define "delay". How much of a delay?

Comment: A delay is frame rate . 0.004 time sleep for 25 fps